# Facebook debugger scrapes default Apache page instead mine

Tags: facebook, apache, meta-tags, og-meta

I made a site: http://pravo-trans.eu/

There is all needed og meta tags. But when I want to share link on any social networks nothings happens. I thought it might be cach. But when I used facebook debugger, it said:

> The 'og:type' property is required, but not present.

And it's not true because I wrote in `<head>` this:

```
    <meta property="og:title" content="Проект правовой помощи людям" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="/transgender-project.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Бесплатные юридические консультации и представительство по делам о смене документов (внесение изменений в записи о рождении, паспорта, трудовые книжки, документы об образовании и другие документы)" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://pravo-trans.eu/" />
    <meta property="og:locale" content="ru_RU" />
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://pravo-trans.eu/" />
```

And most strange thing for me happen when I click on "See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL". **There I saw that debugger parsed Apache default page instead mine**! https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fpravo-trans.eu%2F

How it can be and how I can fix it?

Comment: Looks like there is something mis-configured on your server, so that it responds with only the default page if it does not get exactly the request headers it is expecting. Contact your server admin to investigate this.

Comment: Yes, I already contact with guy who deals with this, but he can check it only after a few days((
Maybe I should write something in .htaccess and it helps?

Answer (score 1):

After several hours of trying to debug this issue and playing with DNS settings/servers, I have a solution that works for me.

I noticed that requests from Facebook were coming from an IPv6 server, but my Apache VirtualHost declarations did not include the IPv6 address. To debug, I changed the following line in my Apache .conf file:

`<VirtualHost IPv4:80>`

to:

`<VirtualHost IPv4:80 [IPv6]:80>`

...and immediately upon restarting Apache, Facebook was able to successfully scrape my site. (Replace IPv4/IPv6 above with your actual addresses of course.)

If by chance you are using Parallels Plesk, as am I, then this is not a permanent solution because Plesk will rewrite the configuration files, so you have to go into the Plesk panel and make sure that your server's IPv6 address is assigned to the Subscription that owns the domain in question. In my case, only the IPv4 was assigned to the subscription.

The setting can be found under "Change Hosting Settings" for each particular Subscription.